# ajax isUpload (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, extjs

I was some time ago busy with ExtJS and ajax. I've have some data in csv format that i return. With ExtJS you can use the option isUpload to popup a file "filename.csv" where you can click save / open etc. Now i'm moving all ExtJS to Jquery and i don't seem to find something which handles this in Jquery, there is no option isUpload in ajax with jquery i guess? Does someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

**Additional Info:**

```
def export(object):
    object = object.order_by('hostname', 'dev_reported_time')
    export = ['test;blub;again;more\n', ]
    for i in object:
        export.append('%s;%s;%s;%s\n' % (i.test, i.blub, i.again, i.more))
    response = HttpResponse(''.join(export), mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.csv'
    return response
```

This is the function that gets called by checking the checkbox. A csv formatted content gets created with the header. I had this working with ExtJS option isUpload, it forced the browser to download the csv file. Now i don't want to use ExtJS anymore, i prefere Jquery or something else. So how to get this csv downloadable? When i check the checkbox at this moment i see the content displaying like the csv format... so the function is working but it doesn't seem to force the browser to download the csv file instead of showing it inside the content.

Watch out, with content i mean, the result is showing inside a div

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use AJAX for this instead of a full round trip to the server?  If you are forcing a download, the current page isn't even unloaded as long as a download happens.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such functionality out of the box built in the jQuery library allowing you to submit forms containing file fields through ajax. You could take a look at the [jQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin. Here's an example:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="/script" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    File: <input type="file" name="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(function() {
        alert('form successfully submited');
    });
});
</script>
```

It will automatically recognize that there's a file field and generate a hidden iframe allowing the upload to work.

Comment: That's not what i meant, At this moment i have a FORM and 1 checkbox called PDF for example. When i CHECK the PDF box my PDF file gets generated (the content of the pdf file in right format) and returns this content while the browser should see this is a 'file' and give a popup to download the file. So Basicly it's not the submit of the form but getting the content as a file download

Comment: Then, this is not a javascript issue, it's a server-side issue. You need to publish your serverside code for us to be able to help.

Comment: i posted some code below, the response i get from my function is just the csv content. I want to browser to force this to download it as a file

Answer (score 0):

def export(object):
        
object = object.order_by('hostname', 'dev_reported_time')
        
export = ['test;blub;again;more\n', ]
        
for i in object:
    
export.append('%s;%s;%s;%s\n' % (i.test, i.blub, i.again, i.more))
        
response = HttpResponse(''.join(export), mimetype='text/csv')
        
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.csv'
        
return response

=+> this is the function that gets called by checking the checkbox. A csv formatted content gets created with the header. I had this working with ExtJS option isUpload, it forced the browser to download the csv file. Now i don't want to use ExtJS anymore, i prefere Jquery or something else. So how to get this csv downloadable? When i check the checkbox at this moment i see the content displaying like the csv format... so the function is working but it doesn't seem to force the browser to download the csv file instead of showing it inside the content.

Watch out, with content i mean, the result is showing inside a div

Comment: On StackOverflow information like this should get edited into the question.  I put it in there for you, so you should probably delete this answer.